# How to make a lua app for PSP?

Tags: scripting, lua, playstation-portable

I am trying to use Luaplayer HM v2 on my PSP, but I am unable to make a simple Helo World app.

I have tried a lot of thing's but it simply doesn't work.
All tutorials, app that I found are for LuaPLayer, I cannot find anything for Luaplayer HM v2.

Please help me I need some tutorials or sampels for Luaplayer HM v2.

Luaplayer app don't work in Luaplayer HM v2. I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best forum for this question. Have you tried [the pspdev.org luaplayer forum](http://forums.ps2dev.org/viewforum.php?f=21)? You might have more luck there.